# In python I can write a log to console but its not getting written into file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

```
import logging 
#Create and configure logger 
logging.basicConfig(filename="newfile.txt", format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filemode='w') 
logging.debug("Harmless debug Message") 
logging.info("Just an information") 
logging.warning("Its a Warning") 
logging.error("Did you try to divide by zero") 
logging.critical("Internet is down")
```

In the console its printing all these informations. Its never written to a file. Really thankful to those help me sort out this. Searching in internet from morning tried all the possibilities but still the logs not writing to file

Comment: the level is logging.INFO and also i have kept it as logging.WARNING but no hope. It prints in  the console but not gets written to a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an new logger with desired stream & file handlers:

```
import logger, sys
logger = logging.Logger('AmazeballsLogger')
#Stream/console output
logger.handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logger.handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
logger.handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(self.handler)
#File output
fh = logging.FileHandler("test.log")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"))
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

And you're ready to take it for a spin:

```
print(logger.handlers)

logger.critical("critical")
logger.error("error")
logger.warning("warning")
logger.info("info")
logger.debug("debug")
```

With the following console output only showing WARNING and higher:

```
[<StreamHandler stdout (WARNING)>, <FileHandler C:\Users\...\test.log (DEBUG)>]
2020-04-13 17:52:57,729 - CRITICAL - critical
2020-04-13 17:52:57,731 - ERROR - error
2020-04-13 17:52:57,734 - WARNING - warning
```

While test.log contains all levels:

```
2020-04-13 17:52:57,729 - AmazeballsLogger - CRITICAL - critical
2020-04-13 17:52:57,731 - AmazeballsLogger - ERROR - error
2020-04-13 17:52:57,734 - AmazeballsLogger - WARNING - warning
2020-04-13 17:52:57,736 - AmazeballsLogger - INFO - info
2020-04-13 17:52:57,736 - AmazeballsLogger - DEBUG - debug
```

The key is to understand how [logging handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) work and checking whether they use correct levels (as in the code cells above, just print logger.handlers). Furthermore, overwriting basic configuration is a bad practice that can lead to problems when you run multiple loggers in the same python environment. I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxmzY9soFXg), it sheds light on stream/file handlers in python logging.

Comment: your answer is correct but import logging instead of logger, and dont use self.handler.   Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I got this example from logging documentation

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    filename='myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
logging.debug('A debug message')
logging.info('Some information')
logging.warning('A shot across the bows')
```

and the examples that I have seen on the web they are all creating `.log`file. So try changing the extension of file from txt to log

Comment: I don't see the log file, only print into tty tho